# Is it possible to modify the HTML flow directly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title suggests I would like to modify how HTML works on a website. For example alter the way display: block works. (Or make my own display property)
I suspect this is impossible but if it isn't I would love to hear how. 
This is something I feel would be useful. If I could freely modify the
HTML flow I would be able to make my own preferred layout setting.

Comment: What **exactly** about how the various layout options available to you (and there are many) leads to to think you need to create a new one? This is way too broad and vague. Voting to Close.

Comment: No. In particular, `display` is a rag-bag of settings that have almost nothing in common with one another, so there's almost no framework on to which one could add new modes.

Comment: @Paulie_D I said modify. Not create. In my opinion you too often need to wrap elements or write a lot of CSS to create the desired effect. I would want to shape how the layout (or flow) works so that you don't need that.

Comment: Then you'll need to create your own browser I suspect.

Comment: I see. Well I don't really got time for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The *display: block inline-block* or *inline* &  v.v, doesn't really modify the document flow.

However, the *display: none;* -will affect the document flow, as the target element will be 'physically' removed, i.e not be rendered at all.

Only the *position: absolute, fixed* and similar will remove the target element from the stream of the document flow. And as a consequence, will affect and modify the flow of the given document.

Comment: Valuable input. Though not what I'm looking for. See the thing is I want to modify how elements behave in a more detailed way than CSS does.